# getImageURL to absolute URL

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a CMS script that allows users to upload and manage content.  The script is on several domains (all accessing a central database).

Here's my problem: When a user creates a store product it is uploaded to the 'main' site and the preview image appears fine.

However if they upload the product from a different domain the product image still uploads on the main site, but the code uses a relative path to find the image and therefore the image is not found.

Here's the product URL portion of the code:

```
$product['vImage_url'] = getImageURL($product['vProductImage'],
$ppa['product_img'][0], $ppa['product_img'][1], '1_',
$site_url.'images/product_default_img.gif');
```

How can I convert this to specify an absolute URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add the main domain somewhere. If all your images are on one domain, I'd define a constant that contains the domain name and use that in the path.

```
// In your config:
define('CDN', '//www.yourimagedomain');

// In your code:
$product['vImage_url'] = CDN . getImageURL($product['vProductImage'],
```

Or, instead of adding it everywhere when you construct an image url, you can add it to the implementation of `getImageURL`, or create a new function like `getProductImageURL` that wraps the concatenation.